# Postgres: Sum of two tables

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have two unrelated tables and would like to sum the values of them by ticker.

For example:

1. Orders: Product_id, value
2. Sales: Product_id, value

In order to make sure that everything balances out to zero, I'd like to group the orders and sales by their product id and sum the values.

Comment: I would be glad to try and help but please post a more accurate example. This is misleading based on the comments posted

Answer (score 0):

```
orders_hash = Order.group(:product_id).sum(:value).sort_by(&:first).to_h
sales_hash  = Sale.group(:product_id).sum(:value).sort_by(&:first).to_h

orders_hash == sales_hash
```

And you can run this check if above is `false`

```
orders_hash.each do |k, v|
  raise "Mismatch for product_id: #{k}" unless sales_hash[k] == v
end
```

Comment: We're ding something similar but is that bad due to the two database calls?

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley how do you see a single DB call to get calculations on 2 unrelated tables? :) Even If this is possible (and in programming nothing is impossible) - it most likely should be rather complicated pure SQL

Comment: I like what you did but I'd like to get the sum rather than see if they're equal. I saw a number of SO posts on sum of unrelated tables but was looking for more clarity. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021623/how-to-do-a-sum-across-two-unrelated-tables

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley I am not that good at SQL, so you should rather wait for more answers

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley it is vice versa - if you have decimals, it should work. You might try casting to decimal while summing (though it should not make a difference if you have decimal in tables): `.sum('value::decimal')`

Comment: The decimal issue was my mistake. :)

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley I am trying to determine how these tables are not related when you are matching based on the same 'product_id'. That seems like a formal relationship to me.

Comment: @engineersmnky - Wrong terminology on my part. I want to stress that the records are from different tables, so they're unrelated when being added by two different people.

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley then how does one make sure "everything balances to zero" there must be some kind of joinable information otherwise you just say sum - sum == 0

Comment: @engineersmnky Andrey's answer works well without needing to make everything zero. By making it zero, it's using accounting standards where your assets should equal your liabilities. :) Before this we were taking the debits - credits = total should be zero. With this answer it's just making sure the debits = credits.

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley This answer relies on the key in one being present in the other (or mismatch) this implies a relationship and if this is true it can could be joined against in SQL. Thus my line of questioning. If this is satisfactory then I will excuse myself but your question suggested SQL might be a plausible option for you

Comment: @engineersmnky - Awesome catch! Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that, as that would cause a big problem for us?